# Request.Form[] always null

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms, web

I have a problem in c# web (aspx, aspx.cs):
I have database with usernames of people and i want to show them in select tag, i did this at the server side to get from the database the usernames and put the as option in select tag:

```
    string tb = "tbUsers";
    string db = "database.mdf";
    string mainConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainConn);
    string querySQL = "SELECT * From " + tb;
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(querySQL, sqlconn);
    sqlconn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    sel.DataSource = dt;
    sel.DataTextField = "userName";
    sel.DataValueField = "userName";
    sel.DataBind();
    sqlconn.Close();
```

and this is the client side with the select tag:

```
            <div class="center">
               <h1>Delete User:</h1>
               <br />
               <select id="sel" name="sel" runat="server" class="form-control">
               </select>
               <br />
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ok</button>
               <br /><br />
               <asp:Label ID="msg" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="black"></asp:Label>
           </div>
```

after this codes in the server side i did an event when the submit button is clicked:

```
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string sel = Request.Form["sel"];
        string query = "";
        query = "SELECT * FROM " + tb + " WHERE userName= '" + sel + "'";
        if (MyAdoHelper.IsExist(db, query))
        {
            query = "DELETE FROM " + tb + " WHERE userName = '" + sel + "'";
            int row = MyAdoHelper.RowsAffected(db, query);
            if (row != 0)
            {
                msg.Text = "deleted";
            }
            else
            {
                msg.Text = "not deleted";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            msg.Text = "try again";
        }
    }
```

but the string called sel allways gets NULL. What i did wrong? 
If someone could help i'll be very thankfull.

**MyAdoHelper is a class with functions that check something they are wrote well and dont have any bugs, in other words - this isnt the problem, ignore them if it needed.**

Sorry for language mistakes if there are**.

Comment: is the element inside a form tag? `<form>.....<select id="sel" name="sel"...>....</form>`?

Comment: of course. i use master page.

Comment: so the code of this page is somewhere inside the form tag of the master page, right? please make sure of this, because if you are not able to get the values, it might be because the element is not inside the form element (you can also check the source code in browser), of postback is not happening but this one I doubt to be true as if you have reached this code, you are inside the ` if (IsPostBack)` condition.

Comment: by the way, I don't see any `<option>` in your select so there are actually no values to be selected. try just adding 1 option for testing `<select...><option value="1">Test</option></select>`